# List all attributes from each element in a taxonomy in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, hierarchical-data

I have a MySQL DB that needs to provide attributes associated with a taxonomy. I desire to have a list of all attributes, including "inherited attributes" for a given element in the taxonomy. I'm not an SQL expert & have learned (and plagiarized) much from this site. One thing I learned here is to use a Closure Table to represent my Hierarchy. What I need to do for my database is associate a large number of attributes to elements within hierarchy.  However, I can't seem to figure out how to grab all of the attributes associated with a given node and all of its parents. I created the following example database for the purpose of this question (feel free to comment on anything about this schema, the fake data is just noise).

My example MySQL database structure looks like this:

```
    -- Simple Sample
    SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
    DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS inheritance_tree_insert;
    DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS inheritance_tree_update;
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS inheritance_paths;
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS inheritance_tree;
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS attributes;
    SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;


    CREATE TABLE `inheritance_tree` (
        `it_id`       INT NOT NULL,           -- PK
        `parent`      INT,                    -- Parent id & FK
        `child_order` INT,                    -- Oder of siblings 
        `name`        VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL,  -- Name for the entry
        PRIMARY KEY (`it_id`),
        FOREIGN KEY (`parent`) REFERENCES inheritance_tree(`it_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
        INDEX(`name`)
    ) ENGINE = INNODB;

    -- Trigger to update the paths table for new entries
    DELIMITER //

    CREATE TRIGGER `inheritance_tree_insert` AFTER INSERT ON `inheritance_tree` FOR EACH ROW 
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO `inheritance_paths` (`ancestor`, `descendant`, `len`)
            SELECT `ancestor`, NEW.`it_id`, len + 1 FROM `inheritance_paths`
                WHERE `descendant` = NEW.`parent`
                UNION ALL SELECT NEW.`it_id`, NEW.`it_id`, 0;
    END; //
    DELIMITER ;


    DELIMITER //
    CREATE TRIGGER `inheritance_tree_update` BEFORE UPDATE ON `inheritance_tree` FOR EACH ROW 
    BEGIN
        -- From http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2011/02/14/moving-subtrees-in-closure-table/
        IF OLD.`parent` != NEW.`parent` THEN
            -- Remove the node from its current parent
            DELETE a FROM `inheritance_paths` AS a
            JOIN `inheritance_paths` AS d ON a.`descendant` = d.`descendant`
            LEFT JOIN `inheritance_paths` AS x
            ON x.`ancestor` = d.`ancestor` AND x.`descendant` = a.`ancestor`
            WHERE d.`ancestor` = OLD.`it_id` AND x.`ancestor` IS NULL;

            -- Add the node to its new parent
            INSERT `inheritance_paths` (`ancestor`, `descendant`, `len`)
            SELECT supertree.`ancestor`, subtree.`descendant`, supertree.`len`+subtree.`len`+1
            FROM `inheritance_paths` AS supertree JOIN `inheritance_paths` AS subtree
            WHERE subtree.`ancestor` = OLD.`it_id`
            AND supertree.`descendant` = NEW.`parent`;
        END IF;
    END; //
    DELIMITER ;


    CREATE TABLE `inheritance_paths` (
        `ancestor`      INT NOT NULL,
        `descendant`    INT NOT NULL,
        `len`           INT NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (`ancestor`, `descendant`),
        FOREIGN KEY (`ancestor`) REFERENCES inheritance_tree(`it_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
        FOREIGN KEY (`descendant`) REFERENCES inheritance_tree(`it_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
    ) ENGINE = INNODB;

    INSERT INTO `inheritance_tree` VALUES(1, NULL, NULL, 'Animal');
    INSERT INTO `inheritance_tree` VALUES(2, 1, 1, 'Mammal');
    INSERT INTO `inheritance_tree` VALUES(3, 1, 2, 'Bird');
    INSERT INTO `inheritance_tree` VALUES(4, 1, 3, 'Reptile');
    INSERT INTO `inheritance_tree` VALUES(5, 2, 2, 'Feline');
    INSERT INTO `inheritance_tree` VALUES(6, 2, 1, 'Bovine');
    INSERT INTO `inheritance_tree` VALUES(7, 1, 3, 'Fish');
    INSERT INTO `inheritance_tree` VALUES(8, 4, 1, 'Snake');
    INSERT INTO `inheritance_tree` VALUES(9, 4, 2, 'Lizard');
    INSERT INTO `inheritance_tree` VALUES(10, NULL, NULL, 'Machine');
    INSERT INTO `inheritance_tree` VALUES(11, 10, 1, 'Automobile');
    INSERT INTO `inheritance_tree` VALUES(12, 10, 2, 'OfficeMachine');
    INSERT INTO `inheritance_tree` VALUES(13, 10, 3, 'Robot');

    DELIMITER ;

    CREATE TABLE `attributes` (
      `a_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'the unique identifier',
      `attribute_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
      `attribute_type` int(11) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`a_id`),
      KEY `fk_attributes_attribute_type1_idx` (`attribute_type`),
      CONSTRAINT `fk_attributes_attribute_type1_idx` FOREIGN KEY (`attribute_type`) REFERENCES `inheritance_tree` (`it_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=0 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

    INSERT INTO `attributes` VALUES(1, 'IsAlive', 1);                   -- Animal
    INSERT INTO `attributes` VALUES(2, 'HasMaximumLifeSpan', 1);        -- Animal
    INSERT INTO `attributes` VALUES(3, 'IsNotAlive', 10);               -- Machine
    INSERT INTO `attributes` VALUES(4, 'HasIndeterminantLifeSpan', 10); -- Machine
    INSERT INTO `attributes` VALUES(5, 'BreathesAir', 2);               -- Mammal
    INSERT INTO `attributes` VALUES(6, 'CanFly', 3);                    -- Bird
    INSERT INTO `attributes` VALUES(7, 'HasFeathers', 3);               -- Bird
    INSERT INTO `attributes` VALUES(8, 'ColdBlooded', 4);               -- Reptile
    INSERT INTO `attributes` VALUES(9, 'HasFourLegs', 5);               -- Feline
    INSERT INTO `attributes` VALUES(10, 'HasFourLegs', 6);              -- Bovine
    INSERT INTO `attributes` VALUES(11, 'ColdBlooded', 7);              -- Fish
    INSERT INTO `attributes` VALUES(12, 'HasNoLegs', 8);                -- Snake
    INSERT INTO `attributes` VALUES(13, 'HasFourLegs', 9);              -- Lizard
    INSERT INTO `attributes` VALUES(14, 'ConsumesGasoline', 11);        -- Automobile
    INSERT INTO `attributes` VALUES(15, 'ConsumesElectricity', 12);     -- OfficeMachine
    INSERT INTO `attributes` VALUES(16, 'ConsumesElectricity', 13);     -- Robot
    INSERT INTO `attributes` VALUES(17, 'WarmBlooded', 2);              -- Mammal
    INSERT INTO `attributes` VALUES(18, 'WarmBlooded', 3);              -- Bird
    INSERT INTO `attributes` VALUES(19, 'BreathesWater', 7);            -- Fish
    INSERT INTO `attributes` VALUES(20, 'HasScales', 8);                -- Snake
    INSERT INTO `attributes` VALUES(21, 'HasSkin', 9);                  -- Lizard
```

Assumptions:

1.All entities in the taxonomy are uniquely named. This means there is one and only one sub-type called “Fish” anywhere in any of the taxonomy trees.

2.Attributes are not unique and may repeat

GOAL:

Given the input type “Lizard” I would like a single query that returns the following list of attribute records:

1, IsAlive, 1

2, HasMaximumLifeSpan, 1

5, BreathesAir, 2

8, ColdBlooded, 4

13, HasFourLegs, 9

21, HasSkin, 9

Comment: How are you associating a_id an attribute to say an inheritence_tree? I would imagine that you would need some sort of association so that you can then cascade the attributes. Maybe that's the very problem you're trying to solve. If so, then use your attributes table as a "look_up" table, from which you tie a inhertience_tree record to, so that means you would add an additional column or have a inheritence_tree_attribute table to make the association. Makes sense?

Comment: The attribute table field 'attribute_type' points to a single node in the hierarchy (inheritance_tree table).

Comment: Here is an example for retrieving the attributes for just Lizard (without inherited attributes): SELECT * FROM attributes WHERE attribute_type IN ( SELECT it_id FROM inheritance_tree WHERE name LIKE 'Lizard')  This results in 2 records returned: 13, HasFourLegs, 9
21, HasSkin, 9

Comment: There seems to be a syntax error here: UNION ALL SELECT NEW.`it_id`, NEW.`it_id`, 0;

Comment: The above loads into my DB without error. But I'll admit I don't understand exactly how the triggers work... but they seem to work for my DB. See http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2011/02/14/moving-subtrees-in-closure-table/
for more details

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.*
FROM   inheritance_tree  t
  JOIN inheritance_paths p ON p.descendant     = t.it_id
  JOIN attributes        a ON a.attribute_type = p.ancestor
WHERE  t.name = 'Lizard'
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f4dce/1/0).

Note that your example output includes `a_id = 5` (BreathesAir), which is a property of `it_id = 2` (Mammal), which is not in the Lizard's ancestry.

Comment: Hey, how did you "sqlfiddleise" the DDL? I tried running the script but it kept failing...

Comment: @RobertoNavarro: sqlfiddle doesn't recognise the `DELIMITER` command (which is a client-side instruction); one needs to change the statement delimiter using the setting beneath the input box and then use that delimiter throughout.

Comment: Awesome! And it is so simple (in comparison to the convoluted SQL I was writing). I need to study th JOIN statement more so I can understand what is going on here. Sorry about the  wrong "BreathesAir"... I did it by hand a little too quiclky. Thanks!